# text-shadow css3 animation / transition not working

Tags: css, animation

I can't work out why this isnt working, I'v checked this against other examples, such as on codePen here:

http://codepen.io/NobodyRocks/pen/qzfoc

my css:

```
.text-header {
    font-family: "oxygenlight";
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color:$bright-yellow;
    -webkit-animation: yellowPulse 2s ease-in-out infinite alternate;
    -moz-animation: yellowPulse 2s ease-in-out infinite alternate;
    -ms-animation: yellowPulse 2s ease-in-out infinite alternate;
    -o-animation: yellowPulse 2s ease-in-out infinite alternate;
    animation: yellowPulse 2s ease-in-out infinite alternate;
}

@-webkit-keyframes yellowPulse {
    from { 
        text-shadow: 
            1px 0px 25px rgba(248,235,51,1),
            0px 1px 25px rgba(248,235,51,1),
            -1px 0px 25px rgba(248,235,51,1),
            0px -1px 25px rgba(248,235,51,1),
            1px 4px 25px rgba(248,235,51,1);
    }
    50% { 
        text-shadow: 
            1px 0px 25px rgba(248,235,51,0),
            0px 1px 25px rgba(248,235,51,0),
            -1px 0px 25px rgba(248,235,51,0),
            0px -1px 25px rgba(248,235,51,0),
            1px 4px 25px rgba(248,235,51,0);
    }
    to {
        text-shadow:
            1px 0px 25px rgba(248,235,51,1),
            0px 1px 25px rgba(248,235,51,1),
            -1px 0px 25px rgba(248,235,51,1),
            0px -1px 25px rgba(248,235,51,1),
            1px 4px 25px rgba(248,235,51,1);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is working for me. I added the transition-property from your reference in the css and set a default text-shadow. If you have an alternate animation and your from and to are equal than you don't need a 50%. Just make your 50% point the to and change the animation speed.

```css
span {
  display: block;
  padding: 50px;
  background: black;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  -moz-transition: all 1s;
  -webkit-transition: all 1s;
  transition: all 1s;
  color: #ff0;
  text-shadow: 0px 0px 0px black;
  -webkit-text-shadow: 0px 0px 0px black;
}

span:hover {
  -webkit-animation: pulse 2s ease-in-out infinite alternate;
  -moz-animation: pulse 2s ease-in-out infinite alternate;
  -ms-animation: pulse 2s ease-in-out infinite alternate;
  -o-animation: pulse 2s ease-in-out infinite alternate;
  animation: pulse 2s ease-in-out infinite alternate;
}

@-webkit-keyframes pulse {
  from {
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 2px blue;
    -webkit-text-shadow: 1px 1px 2px blue;
  }
  to {
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 2px red;
    -webkit-text-shadow: 1px 1px 2px red;
  }
}

@-moz-keyframes pulse {
  from {
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 2px blue;
  }
  to {
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 2px red;
  }
}

@keyframes pulse {
  from {
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 2px blue;
  }
  to {
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 2px red;
  }
}
```

```html
<span class="text-header">Title</span>
```

Comment: Even your code snippet is not working for me, it must be my browser, I'm using Chrome Version 39.0.2171.95 m

Comment: @conor909 Well the text-shadow is not very bright (as I am just using one shadow in comparision to your reference). I made it for the browser I am just online with: firefox 34. I will edit it to make it (theoretically) working under chrome.

Comment: @conor909 Try it with an other more conspicuous property like the text color itself or the background color to have a look whether animations work at all.

Comment: Thanks for your help JoshuaBehrens.  I'v tried it with a basic text color change and it is still not working.  My css is working as the other font properties are taking effect, but no animation.

Comment: @conor909 start chrome in incognito mode and try. Just to make sure neither user scripts nor plugins affecting it. Sorry to say but: even my phone can display it (android with chrome in desktop mode).

Comment: incognito mode is not working either.  I'll keep debugging and post the solution - even if it is a completely stupid thing I'm doing.

Comment: @conor909 I don't want to start a discussion about the best browser but ... how about trying an other browser?

Comment: I have tried on FF and IE.  I'm also using SASS and compass mixins, so possibly something is conflicting, but I cant work out what it is.

Comment: @conor909 Try it raw. I can't try SASS as I never used it and don't know the internal stuff of it.

Comment: Yes it works fine as raw code.  It must be something else going on. If I find the conflicts I'll post it in case anyone else comes across this issue.  Thanks for the response @JoshuaBehrens

Comment: @conor909 I see forward to your answer. Good luck on your search.